# The combobox improperly filter datagridview data

Tags: c#

I face a bug that causes the filter work improperly - that is, when I change the value in combobox then datagridview becomes empty

The code that I use is:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = db.GetInfo()
    .Where(x => x.Title  == cbxSorting.SelectedText)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Double check that `SelectedText` is what you think it is

Comment: @Plutonix, I just want to choose a particular title in combobox and to filter datagridview on chosen title in combobox. I have tried to use cbxSorting.Text it works but there happens confusion, that is, if I choose title of Transport then there is shown data concerning Internet

Comment: Yea, I understood the question.  Look up what `SelectedText` is

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't why, but some time the property "SelectedValue" and "SelectedText" does not work properly, i recommend to you use SelectedItem

```
cbxSorting.SelectedItem?.ToString()
```